# How to prevent second method getting called before first method called in typescript?

Tags: typescript, function, methods, async-await, response

I need to call a method after a API call. I have written the code like this

```
getData(): void {
  this.apiCall();
  this.processAPIData();
}
```

The `processAPIData()` method should be called only after the `apiCall()` is completed and returned a response either success or true. In certain cases, the `apiCall()` is taking more time to return a response and the `processAPIData(`) is getting called before the `apiCall()` is finished. That is causing few issues in the functionality. I have tried using `setTimeout()` for `processAPIData()` but there are chances that the `apiCall()` might take longer time than the time period mentioned in setTimeout.

I don't want to write the `processAPIData()` inside the body of `apiCall()` due to specific requirements and conditions. So can someone kindly help me in resolving this problem.

EDIT: Since some of you have asked about apiCall() structure, I am adding the sample structure of it.

```
apiCall(): void 
{
       this.getAPIData().subscribe((response) => {
       this.dataToBeProcessed = response.data;
      });
}
```

Comment: It's hard to suggest a solution without knowing how apiCall currently looks. But it's probably best, if apiCall returns a Promise and resolves once it is done. Then you can do `this.apiCall().then((result) => this.processAPIData())`

Comment: @A_A I have included the structure of apiCall, It returns a value if success or else an error description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is possible with async functions and Promises.

First of all, you will need to make `this.apiCall` an async function. This makes sure it returns a promise and you can await it.

```js
async apiCall() {
  const res = await this.getAPIData().toPromise()
  this.dataToBeProcessed = res.data
}
```

To be able to wait for the result of `apiCall`, you'll also need to make `getData` async:

```js
async getData() {
  await this.apiCall()
  this.processAPIData()
}
```

EDIT: Use new information provided by OP

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This indeed works fine for the positive scenario that is when the API returns data. But in case it throws an error `this.processAPIData()` is not getting called at all.

Comment: Hey , this depends on your specific implementation of `getAPIData`. I suggest you take a look at RxJS's `catchError` and Error handling in general with RxJS. You can also have a look at promise's `.then().catch()` for error handling on promises.

Comment: Yeah Sure. Thanks for the suggestions, I'll look into those topics!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare getData function as async and use await in apiCall.

```
async getData() {
  await this.apiCall();
  this.processAPIData();
}
```

This is a js functionality.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function